# How to skip rows with wrong data types of an dataset using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Have been working on the dataset cleaning and processing the data for further analysis, I have used different cleaning scripts.

My script gets aborted whenever there is any unwanted / unexceptional data comes up in between the dataset columns, The script execution gets stuck and rest of the data doesn't gets processed.

**Script i have tried using :**

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None 
df = pd.read_excel(open(r'data.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet1')
```

**What I have been expecting :**

How can i process the whole dataset even if there is any exceptional/Unknown datatypes comes up in between the data by skipping and leaving the wrong datatypes as it is.

Any Exception handling method i can use into this.

Please suggest.

Comment: What kind of *exceptional data* can come from an Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: @SergeBallesta - While processing & cleaning some of the columns the datatypes may differ for what we have defined in the script, For Eg. sometimes we process int/float datatypes but gets error when encounters String datatype. Sameway it happens with rest of column with diff datatype vice versa.

Comment: But is the error actually raised at `read_excel` or on your further processing? In the latter case, you should show the code that raises the error along with an example of data.

Comment: @SergeBallesta - just want to ask is there an way to handle  Excel file like error_bad_lines=False that we use in reading CSV file

Comment: You should give a minimal example with (part of) the script that you use to process the dataframe and enough input data to reproduce. Without that your question cannnot be answered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I quite understand the problem.

I have always just done it this way never had problems..

```
import pandas as pd
FileLocation = (r'Test.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(FileLocation, sheet_name='sheet1')
print(df.head)
```

and then you can use a for each loop to iterate over your data frame if you want to go and remove wrong data.

But if you have problems with the excel reader reading it as float but want it as string you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
FileLocation = (r'Test.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(FileLocation, sheet_name='sheet1', converters={'COLUMN-NAME':str})
print(df.head)
```

Then you would get the wanted column as a string or whatever you want.